# What is The Judge?

Tags: dialogue, armageddon

In [Armageddon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_%281998_film%29), what tool was Harry Stamper referring to when he said

> "unpack The Judge"

after the drill bit broke?

Answer (score 4):

"The Judge" is nothing more than a really large drill bit.  There's no real reason I could figure out as to how it got that name, but that's what they unpack and put on the end of the rig.

Comment: I think it was just for dramatic flair.  The other option must have been some variation on "get me the biggest drill bit!"

Comment: They shoulda called it "The Jury" or "The Hammer" or something.  "Get me the Hammer of Grapthar!"  :oD

Comment: @JohnnyBones "Oh what a savings"

Answer (score 0):

The "Judge" is a large, high-tech drill bit with multiple spinning parts.

[image]

Interestingly, in the [original script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Armageddon.pdf) they were going to call it "The Terminator". I would assume that this ran into a rights issue.

> **HARRY:** *Go to the Terminator.*
>
> **Chick grabs Harry's mysterious METAL CASE. Harry pops open the metal case, revealing THE TERMINATOR, a super high-tech bit.**
>
> **HARRY:** *I designed you. I built you. You are the enemy of all subterranean shit. You are the king. It's showtime.*
>
> Harry passes it to Bear, who screws it onto the drilling pipe,
>   Rockhound scoops  up a COLLECTION OF DOWNHOLE ROCK CHIPS.
>
> **HARRY** (CONT'D):  *Hit it, Chick.*
>
> The DRILL PIPE turns. Sediment comes WHOOSHING out of the hole and —
>   THE DRILL PIPE descends like a bitch.

Comment: Given the repeated references to "dropping the hammer", I'm guessing that's why he called it The Judge.